# RegExp: Match a string that not contain a given word

Tags: regex

I want to check whether a string does not contain a string, such as:

```
str1 = "He is a minion, he's so funny."
str2 = "He is not a minion, he's funny."
str3 = "He is not a minion, he's also funny."
```

And I need to check which string doesn't contains `not` and `also`. So, the expected result is: `str1` is `false`, `str2` is `false`, `str3` is `true`.

What is regexp?

Comment: Which regex engine or language are you using?

Comment: Why not use String#contains?

Comment: Any engine and language, I just want to know more about regexp.

Comment: @funny337 Well, regexp differs from language to language. Please read the regex wiki page.

Comment: @Terry Li: Because some special case, I need many excepted words, and I don't want to make my if clause to long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find lines that contain multiple words, use a positive look ahead

```
(?=.*\bnot\b)(?=.*\balso\b).*
```

Regular expression:

```
(?=           look ahead to see if there is:
 .*          any character except \n (0 or more times)
 \b           the boundary between a word char and something that is not a word char
  not         'not'
 \b           the boundary between a word char and something that is not a word char
)             end of look-ahead
(?=           look ahead to see if there is:
 .*          any character except \n (0 or more times)
 \b           the boundary between a word char and something that is not a word char
  also         'also'
 \b           the boundary between a word char and something that is not a word char
)             end of look-ahead
.*            any character except \n (0 or more times)
```

[**Live Demo**](http://www.regex101.com/r/jD3hK4)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a series of look-aheads:

```
(?=.*not)(?=.*also).*
```

Comment: JS Usage for OP: `if(str.match(/(?=.*not)(?=.*also).*/)!=null)`

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I need a keyword to search on Google, now I found more help at: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem without lookahead. Used the **x** modifier to make regex easier to understand.

```
/.*? \b not \b .*? \b also \b | .*? \b also \b .* \b not \b/x
```